# How far can Minecraft mob pathfind

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm building a custom mob farm in MCPE v 1.1.2 where the mobs try to walk over open trap doors but fall in a water stream. **I'm wondering how far mobs can pathfind** so that if a mob is at the edge of the farm it can pathfind to the other edge.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [site](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie) under the "Behavior" tab, zombies can chase the player from up to 40 blocks away, however, all other hostile mobs will only detect the player from 16 blocks away (except for endermen and zombie pigmen. They have to be provoked). So, if your trap is small enough, you can stand at the end of it and letthem come to you.

Comment: Mobs will *chase* the player a significantly higher distance than *spot* him/her - once aggravated, the mob is quite difficult to "lose", Over [32m away](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/116945/what-is-the-optimum-player-position-respective-to-mob-grinder) the mobs won't even move unless aggro'ed. As for mob farms, most efficient designs involve pushing the mobs one way or another (water, pistons etc) or baiting/scaring them (villager, endemite, wolf, cat) - farms that depend on mobs walking into a hole randomly are notoriously inefficient.

Comment: The only efficient farms where the player is the bait are zombie pigmen farms. In normal mob farms, skeletons will not try to chase the player, but to position to shoot. Takes some wild creativity to aggro the skeletons and not get shot... creativity better spent on pushing the skelies into kill zone instead.